# Window refresh After Other Window close

Tags: powerbuilder

How can I refresh a window when clicking the close button of a other window?

The other window is a Response Window.

I use PowerBuilder 12.5

Comment: Your question is very broad and unclear and might be closed as such. To improve the quality of your question, you can [provide some code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and add precisions about what you mean by the following terms: *refresh a window, response window*. Also, precise your OS. Edit your question accordingly, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to pass a reference into the response window for the “other window” (if you’re already passing in a parameter, you can pass in multiple parameters in a custom powerobject), store it in an instance variable, then fire off a “refresh” event (iw_OtherWindow.TriggerEvent()) on the other window at an appropriate time during the close logic of your response window.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check the valid status of refresh required window in close query event of that closing window.
If the valid status is true then do the refresh code.

Best of luck.